# An array of object pointers as parameter

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
class Warrior {
    public: 
       char* type;
       int health;
       Warrior(char* itype, int ihealth) {
           strcpy(type, itype);
           health = ihealth;
       }
       Warrior(const Warrior* w) {
           strcpy(type, w->type);
           health = w->health;
       }
       // Warrior() { }
};

// headquarter
class HeadQuarter {
    private:
        Warrior warrior[5];
        ...

    public:
        HeadQuarter(Warrior *w[5], int icap, int ihealth[5]) {
            init();
            capacity = icap;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) warrior[i] = *w[i];         
        }
};
```

Hi every body, when I am trying pass an array of `Warrior` poiters to  construct my `HeadQuarter` class, it tells me I need empty arguments constructor Warrior::Warrior() to do this. Is that means it try to construct the object when I am passing pointers?

Comment: By the way, `strcpy(type, itype);` without assigning valid buffer to `type` is bad. Why not use `std::string`?

Comment: Use `std::array` or `std::vector` and pass by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Warrior warrior[5];
```

Here you are declaring an array of `Warrior` objects. This array, whether it's a global variable, or a member of a class, must be instantiated. This means that the `Warrior` class must be constructed. Since you do not see any constructor parameters anywhere around here, it logically means that `Warrior` must have a default constructor.

It is possible to instantiate an array of classes, like this, using the initializer syntax; but you still will need to come up with the constructor/initializer parameters, in that case.

```
public: 
   char* type;
   int health;
   Warrior(char* itype, int ihealth) {
       strcpy(type, itype);
       health = ihealth;
   }
```

Here, the `Warrior` constructor is `strcpy()`ing into a pointer that has not been initialized. Pretty much a guaranteed crash.

It's better to stop writing this kind of error-prone C-style code, and write real C++ code, instead of C code. That means using a `std::string`, for `type`; which avoids this entire problem altogether.

Answer (score 0):

This is not because you are passing an array. This is because of the following line in your class:

```
Warrior warrior[5];
```

This tries to call a default constructor of Warrior, but there is no default constructor. Hence the error.

Your `Warrior` constructor is plain bad. Copying into uninitialized `char*` is a recipe for disaster.

On a side note, your function signature doesn't do what you might expect it to do. Size of the array argument is ignored, because arrays are decayed to pointers when passed to functions, and could be written as

```
HeadQuarter(Warrior** w, int icap, int* ihealth)
```

Comment: hi, what should I do when I want to specify the size of the pointers array?

Comment: @PeterLai, you should use `std::array` :)